# Facebook crawler in messenger bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is the Facebook crawler available to messenger bots? As a tester on the development version of a bot, URLs sent by the bot are raw. Is this something automatically available once a bot goes public or do developers have to rely on templates?